# Firebase Analytic for Phonegap/Cordova App

Tags: cordova, firebase, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, firebase-analytics

I have developed fews apps using Phonegap/Cordova. I'd like to integrate Firebase Analytics instead of Google Analytics. Is it possible? Is there any Cordova Plugin for Firebase Analytics? Please explain.

Also I don't find web support for Firebase Analytics in the official [documentation samples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/)

Comment: Please explain what is wrong in above question?
All I need is how to integarte firebase analytic in cordova? Do you thing anything wrong in this question? I dont find any document to integrate firebase analytic in cordova/phonegap so raising it in stackoverflow. why you have downvoted? you dont want to use firebase in cordova??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one firebase plugin for cordova (I'm the author)

https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase

Comment: Can you suggest me why below screen isn't updated on Analytic DashBoard? document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
window.FirebasePlugin.setScreenName('Redeem Vouchers') },true);  I assume that, space is supported in screen name.

Answer (score 3):

Wasted several hours on this, here is what I found:

**Add app to firebase console**

- Create a project
- Add an app, use the package name (com.x.y.app)

**Installation**:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase --save
cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release --save  --variable PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=16.+
cordova prepare && cordova compile
```

**Code**:

```
initializeAnalytics() {
    window.FirebasePlugin.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true); // Enables analytics collection
    window.FirebasePlugin.setScreenName("Home");

    window.FirebasePlugin.logEvent("select_content", { content_type: "page_view", item_id: "home" });

    // window.FirebasePlugin.setUserId("user_id");
    // window.FirebasePlugin.setUserProperty("name", "value");
}
```

**Solving the build error**:
I had below error:

> The library com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl is being
>   requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.2,15.0.2],
>   [16.3.0,16.3.0]], but resolves to 16.3.0. Disable the plugin and check
>   your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

The solution was since it is resolving at 16.3.0, I changed all PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION in the entire project

```
change all code:
        from        "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "15.+"  
        to          "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "16.+"
```

But before above, I had done:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

But, be careful to have a copy of your platform directory, maybe you did some changes in that directory, though ideally, you shouldn't, but as a beginner, you will as many other solutions suggest you do it.

**Upload the app**:

With all integration done, upload the app to Play console.

**Check your firebase console**

After several hours waiting, after some downloads happened, it showed below screenshot.

[image]

**Links**:

https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase
https://firebase.google.com/docs/
https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/
https://firebase.google.com/docs/libraries/

Hope that helps.

---

**Update**

I wrote the app in Cordova + Reactjs.

Now a days, it is better create in [React Native](https://flutter.dev/) Or [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/)

Comment: Hi, I'm getting this error: Error in Success callbackId: PushNotification1149818716 : TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled' of undefined. Did you experience this issue?

Comment: The above means `someThing1.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled()` is used, but `someThing1` is undefined.

Comment: all i needed was `cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release --save  --variable PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=16.+`

Comment: Thanks for the guide. Apologies for the daft question, but where do you place the code above? In index.html?

Comment: I actually forgot where it is. Most probably it is the mobile app i wrote in Cordova+Reactjs. Now a days, it is better create in React Native Or Flutter

Answer (score 1):

Another Cordova plugin, although this is only for Analytics (one: https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics

To debug your events remember to properly configure your apps as [described here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7201382?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489).

Comment: Wow, you just saved my @$$ - wasted a few days having no clue what was going on and why I wasn't see my data consistently... this really saved me, thank you!